# How to remove the original indexes and set new indexes in a quick way? (Python language)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My code is here:

```
df['sway_diff'] = df['selfLR'] - np.where(df.vote.eq(0), df['ClinLR'], df['DoleLR'])
print(f"The largest difference between a respondent's political leaning and their impression of their intended candidate's political leaning is {df.sway_diff.max()}")
num_of_diff = len(df[df['sway_diff'] == 6])
print(f"There're {num_of_diff} respondent(s) have that magnitude.")

#sway df
sway = df[df['sway_diff'].abs() >= 3]
sway = sway.reset_index()
sway.index += 1

print(f"{len(sway[sway['sway_diff'] < 0 ])} respondents are more liebral")
print(f"{len(sway[sway['sway_diff'] > 0 ])} repondents are more conservative")
print(f"{len(sway[sway['vote'] == 1])} respondents vote for Dole")
print(f"{len(sway[sway['vote'] == 0])} respondents vote for Clinton")
```

The dataFrame 'sway' is a new dataFrame extracts from the 'df' and remains the previous indexes.

How to remove those indexes and add new indexes? I put a screen capture below, hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sway = df[df['sway_diff'].abs() >= 3].reset_index(drop=True)
# below is to increase the index by 1.
sway.index = sway.index + 1
```

delete the line `sway = sway.reset_index()`